# Copy-paste with multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, filter, copy-paste

The VBA code below represents a copy-paste function, filtered by two conditions. The code works and gets the job done, but the problem is the time for it to generate the results - Is there anyone here who knows a more efficient way to write the same code? 
Any suggestions are highly appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

  Dim c As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer


  Range("N6:R50").ClearContents
  i = 0
  For Each c In Range("B2:B50")
    If c = Range("O3").Value And Month(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = Range("P1").Value Then
      Cells(6 + i, 14) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 1)
      Cells(6 + i, 15) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 1)
      Cells(6 + i, 16) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 2)
      Cells(6 + i, 17) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 3)
      Cells(6 + i, 18) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 4)
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next c
   For j = 50 To 6 Step -1
    If Cells(j, 15) = "" Then
      Range("N" & j, "R" & j).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
  Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share an example of the data set you have?
Possible solution might be to apply filters on column A and B and then copy values for filtered rows (instead of thee loop).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (you might change ranges [6] depending on your headers):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long
Application.ScreenUpadting = False
LR = Range("N6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 5
Range("N6:R" & LR).ClearContents
LR = Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 5
Range("A6").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, Range("P1")
Range("A6").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 2, Range("O3")
If Range("A6").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count > 1 Then
    Range("N6:N" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("B7:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    Range("O6:R" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("C7:F" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    Range("A6").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    Set rng = Range("N7:R" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code and almost everything got deleted - Maybe it is because  there are alot of other formulas written in several cells?